Finding related items in OpenSearch between 2 datasets
I have a scenario where I have 2 sets of data:

All possible products
Products carried by a store

Dataset 2 is a subset of dataset 1.
If a user searches for a product that the store doesn't carry, I'd like to be able to return similar products from the search. The problem is that product names don't indicate what category/subcategory they belong in so right now I just get text-based search results.
So let's say a user searches for a self-help book by name, but the store doesn't carry it. I'd like to recommend other self-help books.
Conceptually, I'd be able to search dataset 1 to get all of the relevant information about the book and then use that to search dataset 2, but I'm having trouble approaching how I'd go about doing that.
Right now I have the datasets in OpenSearch and I'd like to use that as I intend to pass the search results through an Amazon Personalize campaign to re-rank the items for the user searching.

A "more like this" query can return similar documents but is purely text based. If you can vectorize your documents using some ML embeddings model you can do a knn query, and the chosen model might cluster self-help topics close to each other. But there's no real substitute for data quality, tagging all products with metadata that you can use for precise filtering. If you only have a few thousand SKUs, manual tagging is probably the way to go.

You are describing a need for a
recommender system.
There is a rich literature on this topic for you to consult,
with many implementations.
You didn't mention data volumes,
nor how much consumer behavior you're able to view.
E-commerce search, browsing, and purchase behavior
can inform a model about your demographic of interest.

say a user searches for a self-help book by name

Fortunately the special case of "book" has some helpful
metadata associated with it.
For a given SKU we are likely to know both Title and Author.
A specific author will tend to write books that are thematically
similar, inducing graph edges among their published works.
In the same way two products in a checkout basket induce an
edge suggesting small distance between the products,
though it's harder to collect that information.
Staff involved in producing music or a film represent
the same kind of metadata.
Pin down your data and dollar budget, and try out a suitable implementation.
